# Date() object inconsistency. Month, day and year are all wrong

Tags: java, android, java.util.date, date

Right now is 3/15/11 and when I'm calling a new date object:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

I'm getting in return

- the month as 2 (`getMonth()`),
- the day as 2 (`getDay()`)
- and the year (`getYear()`) as 111.

Is there a reason for this convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from [the class's documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> - A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.
> - A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.
> - A date (day of month) is represented by an integer from 1 to 31 in the usual manner.

And as for [`getDay()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29):

> Returns the day of the week represented by this date. The returned value (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday) represents the day of the week that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

March 15th 2011 is in fact a Tuesday.

Comment: On top of that, **all of those methods are deprecated** as of JDK 1.1.

Comment: Exactly. Don't use these. Use Calendar instead, or better yet JodaTime.

Comment: Can you give me an example of Calendar or JodaTime?

Comment: Calendar has it's quirks as well (months start at 0, the existence of [`UNDECIMBER`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#UNDECIMBER)). The larger point of simply reading the class's documentation remains.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason for this convention?

The reason is that it is what the javadoc for Date specifies; see @matt b's answer.

The `Date` APIs were created in the days of JDK 1.0, and are well known to be problematic in a number of areas.  That is why most of the Date methods are marked as Deprecated.  (By the way, that means that it is recommended that you don't use them in new code!!)

The `Calendar` APIs are a significant improvement on `Date`, but the best by far APIs for handling date / time values in Java are the 3rd-party [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) APIs.

---

If you want examples of Joda time usage, look at the link above.  There's an example of Calendar usage in the [`GregorianCalendar` javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).  More examples of Calendar usage may be found on [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/0580__Calendar.htm).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                              // Modern class to represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )    // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region (a time zone).
.getYear()                             // Get year number, such as 2019 presently.
```

…and:

```
.getMonthValue()                       // Get month number, 1-12 for January-December.
```

…and:

```
.getDayOfMonth()                       // Get day-of-month number, 1-31.
```

## Details

Apparently you are using either of two terrible date-time classes, `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`. Both are outmoded as of the adoption of JSR 310, defining their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Accessing parts of a date

The *java.time* classes use sane numbering, 1-12 for months, 1-7 for days of the week, the year number such as 2019 is the year 2019, and such.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;                 // The year, such as 2019 presently.
int monthNumber = ld.getMonthValue() ;    // Number of the month 1-12 for January-December.
Month month = ld.getMonth() ;             // Get the `Month` enum object, one of a dozen predefined objects (one for each month of the year). 
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;     // Get the day of the month, 1-31.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).